# How do you get music?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've looked at questions on how to get music and the only answers were with club LOL. I don't have club LOL. So how can you get music without club LOL?

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to get music:

- Attend K.K. Slider's live performance on a Saturday night after 8:00 PM

  - Max: 1 per week
  - Price: Free
  - Option to select any one song (except K.K. Birthday, which can only be played on the Saturday on your birthday week)

or

- Buy a copy from the Nookling store (T.I.Y. or higher)

  - Max: 1 per day (T.I.Y.) or 2 per day (T&T Emporium)
  - Price: 3200 bells
  - Random song(s) available each day

You'll need to get either Club LOL or several renovations to the Nookling store in order to get music for yourself, but if you have a friend who is willing you help you out, they are tradeable, and you can buy them from Nookling stores in other players' towns.

Answer (score 0):

You can get KK Slider music at TIY/T&T Emporium for 3,200 Bells and at Club LOL for free(Saturday night). You can also get music by having a friend drop it in your town and you can pick it up, put it in your stereo and it will play music!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you have someone you have met via spotpass then there is a chance that they have some music on display in their homes (from the HHA showcase). That is how I found my first music anyway.